# Referencing fields in code block of Field Calculator in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, modelbuilder, field-calculator

[image: Snip of my Calculate Field window with code block and expression.]

I'm trying to use values from a field to fill a new field with a truncated version. The 'str.rindex' function is working out well, but I can't seem to figure out how I'm supposed to reference the field I need truncated. I found a few answers on here explaining that the !field! convention won't work, but no solutions for a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the code block you'll define a function, and then in the expression, you'll call the function with the needed field names, like so :

Code block :

```
def picture_name(current_name, map_number):
    return current_name[current_name.rindex("\\"):] + "|" + map_number + ".tif"
```

Expression :

```
picture_name(!Pictures!, !MapNumber!)
```

I haven't test this code, and I rewrote a bit of the logic. Hopefully this at least gets you closer.

Comment: This looks good to me, I'll give it a shot and report back. Thanks much.

Comment: This appears to be working. The final result is pulling the fields just fine. The truncation is getting a bit off, but that was not part of my original question. As far as I'm concerned this answer was a great success. **Things to watch out for** this needs everything to be in a string field, so watch what you're pulling from if you are trying to do a similar function.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I should have figured MapNumber might not be a string field. You can just change it to... + "|" + str(map_number) + ".tif"